# In C++ storing and retrieving of character vector (vector<char>) of all zero value (i.e. '\0' or string terminator) from file

Tags: c++

Using `fstream` I have created a file to store a fixed length sequence of zero value (0) i.e. '\0' ASCII code available in a character vector (vector).

```
fstream Fpt;

Fpt.open("Data.bin",ios::out|ios::binary);

std::vector<char> V;

char c=0;

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)V.push_back(c);

Fpt.write((char *)&V,10);

Fpt.close();

Fpt.open("Data.bin",ios::in | ios::out|ios::binary);

V.clear();

Fpt.read((char *)&V, 10);

for(auto v: V) printf("(%c,%d,%X)",v,v,v);
```

But the output is looking like (▌,-35,FFFFFFDD) (▌,-35,FFFFFFDD) ...

Comment: prototype of write method is ostream& write (const char* s, streamsize n);. use should use char* instead of &vector

Comment: A `vector` has more than just the data inside

Answer (score 2):

You write the vector object itself, not the data wrapped by the vector (which is located on the heap).

You need to get a pointer to the data itself and write that:

```
Fpt.write(V.data(), V.size());
```

Similarly when you read the data, you need to read it into the wrapped data:

```
V = std::vector<char>(10);  // Reset the vector, remembering to set its size
Fpt.read(V.data(), V.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

This statement is not correct:

```
Fpt.write((char *)&V,10);
```

You are getting the address of the vector object `V` which is stored on the stack. What you want is the address of the underlying buffer (stored on the heap) that `V` points at and so you need to use the `data` member function.

So instead do this:

```
Fpt.write( V.data(), 10 );
```

Or this:

```
Fpt.write( &V[0], 10 );
```

#### Important Note

What you do here is a bad idea:

```
char c=0;

for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) V.push_back(c);
```

This will cause the vector to repeatedly reallocate its buffer once the size reaches capacity. This is bad in terms of performance.
Instead, write it like:

```
std::vector<char> V(10);
```

Now `V` will be initialized with 10 `\0` characters. No need to use a loop to fill the container.